# Creating validation rule using two multi picklist

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist, validation, dependent-picklist

I have two Multi picklist, One is State__c and another one is Job__c.
In Job__c, Doctor(picklist value) can only be selected when the State__c selected has NewYork(picklist value).
Otherwise it should not allow us to save.

I tried something like this but not working.

```
IF((CONTAINS(States__c ,'NewYork')), ISPICKVAL(Job__c, "Doctor"), null)
```

> Error: Field States__c is a multi-select picklist field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. 
 If you click the help link in that error message, you'll see a [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5) that explains what you can do.  Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want INCLUDES...

```
IF(INCLUDES(Job__c, "Doctor") ,
IF(INCLUDES(States__c, "NewYork"), false, true)
, false)
```

Helpful?!

Comment: yeah, Working. Thanks alot